# Stability of fixed points for ODE range

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, stability-in-odes

Given the ordinary differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^3 - 2x^2 + (1- \mu)x,$$

where $\mu$ is a parameter, I want to find an expression for the fixed point(s) $x^*$ as a function of $\mu$; and to determine the stability of fixed points.

In my working out I find that the fixed points are $x^* = 0$ and also $x^* = 1±\sqrt{\mu}$. So when I try to find the stability of the fixed points, my lecturer says to consider the three regions:

$$\mu < 0 ;$$
$$0 < \mu < 1;$$
$$\mu > 1.$$

My question is: I do not get why he considers these regions.
Why not consider $\mu < 0$, $\mu = 0$ and $\mu >0$ for example?

I am fine evaluating the stability, but I do not get understand how to determine the intervals - any clarification on this would be welcome.

This is the sketch of the curve for reference: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t1y2i9y7lr

Edit - I understand that I will need to calculate the eigenvalues - can anyone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Your professors hint indicates that the eigenvalues may change qualitatively between $0<\mu<1$ and $\mu>1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask how you/he knows that and further how this helps in the question. I did not think to evaluate the eigenvalues for a nonilnear ode.

Comment: Can anyoone please elaborate on this

Answer (score 1):

As you found, there will be equilibrium points at $x=0$ and $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{\mu}$.

- If $\mu < 0$, then $\sqrt{\mu}$ is undefined (over the reals), so there is only one equilibrium point.
- If $\mu = 0$, then $1 \pm \sqrt{\mu} = 1 \pm 0 = 1$, so there are only two equilibrium points.
- If $ 0 < \mu < 1$, then $1 + \sqrt{\mu}>1 - \sqrt{\mu}>0$ are all distinct values and we have three equilibrium points.
- If $\mu = 1$, then $1 - \sqrt{\mu} = 0$, so there are only two equilibrium values.
- If $\mu > 1$, then $1 + \sqrt{\mu} > 0 > 1 - \sqrt{\mu}$ and we have three distinct equilibrium values.

Therefore, we have three regions with distinctly different dynamics: $\mu < 0$, $0 < \mu < 1$, and $\mu > 1$, with *bifurcations* occuring at $\mu =0$ and $\mu =1$. See the following plot which gives the equilibrium values as a function of $\mu$:

[image: Phase Portrait]